# Access images uploaded to one CakePHP app from another CakePHP app

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a CakePHP project whare i have given the user the ability to upload profile images. The images are uploaded to the `webroot/uploads/users` folder. I need to have another CakePHP project that acts as a admin panel for the first app. I need to display the images uploaded to the first project in the admin panel.

I can have the admin panel project either inside the first CakePHP project or as a separate project. What i'm telling is something like this. Either

```
www.example.com/admin/ <= Inside the first project
www.admin.example.com/ <= In a sub domain
```

It doesn't matter which way it is. But my problem is that i have no idea of how to access the images in `webroot/uploads/users/` folder from the admin panel project.. How can i do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very problem when creating a front facing site with a cms admin panel. I got around it by setting up symbolic links on the server to the specific image folders:

```
sudo ln -s /var/www/example.com/subdomains/admin/httpdocs/app/webroot/img/profile_images /var/www/example.com/httpdocs/app/webroot/img/profile_images
```

Any images uploaded on the admin site are then immediately available on the other site. It isn't a CakePHP solution but it does the job.

Comment: Do i have to do this at the point of hosting the solution? can you explain a little more? how can i do this on my development server? I use wamp.

Comment: Once you know the folder you'll have to manually do it on the server. That code was used on a Ubuntu server. To test locally on your dev server would depend on your OS - from Mac you can do the same in Terminal or on Windows search Google for "windows symbolic link"